# Set of cluster points of a sequence is empty if the sequence diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

We say that $a\in\operatorname{clus}\left(x_{n}\right)$ if, and only if, there is a subsequence of $\left(x_{n}\right)$ that converges to $a$.

Let $\left(x_{n}\right)$ be a sequence in the metric space $\left(X,d\right)$, where $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{m}$. Show that if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\|x_{n}\right\|_{2}=\infty$, then $\operatorname{clus}\left(x_{n}\right)=\emptyset$.

My attempt: If $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\|x_{n}\right\|_{2}=\infty$, then $\left(x_{n}\right)$ is unbounded. That is, for all $M\in\mathbb{R}$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\left\|x_{n}\right\|_{2}>M$. By the triangle inequality, $M<\left\|x_{n}\right\|_{2}=\left\|x_{n}-x_{n_{k}}+x_{n_{k}}\right\|_{2}\le\left\|x_{n}-x_{n_{k}}\right\|_{2}+\left\|x_{n_{k}}\right\|_{2}$.

I'm not sure if I'm headed in the right direction or not. I want to show that every subsequence of $\left(x_{n}\right)$ is unbounded, which means the subsequence doesn't converge and thus doesn't have a limit, so $\operatorname{clus}\left(x_{n}\right)$ is empty, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Do you know the fact that if $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = g$ then every subsequence of $a_n$ converges to $g$ ?

Comment: @Adayah yes but I thought that only held for finite $g$.

Comment: Also holds for $g = \infty$, and the proof goes alike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: It is true that $(x_n)$ is unbounded, but it is even more true: The condition $\lim_{n\to\infty}||x_n||=\infty$ also implies that for each $M>0$ there is some index $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $||x_n||\geq M$ holds FOR ALL $n\geq N$.

Can this sequence now have a bounded subsequence?